# React-Native handling platform dependent type faces (fonts)

Tags: react-native

Hey does anyone happen to know, how to handle cross platform font stylings in iOS and Android ? I am trying to google this and there appears to be no results. That is I want roboto for android and sanfranciso for iOS, is there a best practice for handling this ?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7033

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7033

So this answers the question to the style sheet problem!